# Constructing a homomorphism from $G$ to $S_t$ and finding it's order

Tags: group-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ with index $t$. Let $X$ be the set of left cosets of $H$ in $G$, so that
$|X| = t$. Then $G$ acts on $X$ by left translation: $g · (xH) := (gx)H$.

(a) Use this to construct a homomorphism from $G$ to $S_t$.

(b) Show that if $G$ is simple then $|G| \leq t!$.

a) I think I have. I have let $X = \{x_1H,...,x_tH\}$. Then when $g$ acts of $x_1H$ we get $(gx_1H)$ but $(gx_i)$ is in a coset so without loss of generality say $gx_1H$ is in $x_2H$. Then we have a homomorphism sending $\sigma(1)=2$ Thus $\sigma:G \to S_t$ , $\sigma(i)=j$ where $j$ is the coset $gx_i$ is in.

Any feedback on a) would be much appreciated.

b) I feel this is an application of Poincares theorem but I am not too sure where to start, could someone put me on the right path? Thanks

Comment: By the way, what you call $X$ already has a standard notation:  $G / H$.

Comment: @SammyBlack, that could easily be confused with a quotient group, which exists iff $\;H\lhd G\;$

Comment: *As sets,* they are the same thing!  I have seen that notation used for left cosets, regardless of whether the cosets enjoy the additional structure of a group.

Answer (score 0):

**(a)** You have the right idea.  After enumerating $X = G/H = \{x_1 H, \ldots, x_t H\}$, define $\varphi: G \to S_t$ implicitly by noting that for any $g \in G$, we have $gx_i H = x_{\sigma(i)} H$ for all $1 \le i \le t$, and setting $\varphi(g) = \sigma$.

**(b)** By the "First" Isomorphism theorem, 
$$
G / \ker \varphi \cong \operatorname{Im} \varphi \le S_t.
$$
Since $G$ is simple and $\ker \varphi$ is a *normal* subgroup of $G$, we may conclude that the kernel is either trivial ($\varphi$ is an isomorphism) or all of $G$ ($\varphi$ is trivial).  You can show that the latter doesn't happen.  So, looking at the orders of these groups,
$$
|G| = \frac{|G|}{|\ker \varphi|} = | \operatorname{im} \varphi | \quad \text{divides} \quad |S_t| = t!
$$
so $|G| \le t!$.